# Find the limit given.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

If $z = x + iy$,  then the value of
$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 3 - 4i} \dfrac{i~\text{Re}(z)^2}{|z|}$ is....

My attempt:
I get that the function of the limit should be
$\dfrac{i~(x^2 - y^2)^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} $
after we substitute $|z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $\text{Re}(z)^2 = (x^2 - y^2)^2$, but I can't continue after this step. If we substitute $x$ so what the limit wants, then it leads to more complicated form. Please, could you help me?

Comment: Surely it should be $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to3-4i}\cdots\,$?

Comment: $z^2=-7-24i$ so $Re(z)^2=-7$ and so numerator is $-7i$. You can do denominator?

Comment: @david no it is x

Comment: @imranfat Where do you get $z^2 = -7 - 24i$?

Comment: @ShaneDizzySukardy I misread $x$ for $z$. Sorry

Comment: There is nothing more you can do than putting $x=3-4i$. The answer is obviously dependent on y and not much simplifications is possible.

Comment: But the choice given is $2i, 3i, 4i, 5i, 6i$ which means that $y$ is eliminated in that fraction forms.